# how to remove video downloading option from video?

Tags: html

i want to remove downloading option from video how can i do it?

```
<video src="admin/upload/<?php echo $row['files']?>" class="img-fluid card-img-top" style="width:286px; height:250px;" alt="..."></video>   // main view of video icon
             <a href="admin/upload/<?php echo $row['files']?>" class="venobox play-btn mb-4"data-vbtype="video" data-autoplay="true" ></a>   //link to view actual file
```

Comment: @HarunYilmaz as you can see i use <a> tag to link video is it possible to remove downloading option from <a> tag?

Comment: I guess you need to check the documentation of `VenoBox` since you want to open video in a modal with the plugin. And I think the CSS approach will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

add `controlsList="nodownload"`

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" controlsList="nodownload" type="video/mp4">
  
</video>
```

[mdn](https://wicg.github.io/controls-list/html-output/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-media-controlslist)

Comment: This attribute is not supported by all browsers. https://www.caniuse.com/#search=controlsList